# alternatives to name hiding inherited non virtual functions

Tags: c++, overloading, name-hiding

```
struct Base
{
  int x;
  int foo() const
  {
    return x;
  }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  int y;
  int foo() const
  {
    return Base::foo() + y;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Derived d;
  d.x = 1;
  d.y = 2;
  const Base& b = d;
  std::cout << b.foo() << std::endl;
  std::cout << d.foo() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have this design issue. Two simple structs that are used to wrap some members which are accessed directly in parts of the code (The base has more members than shown). There is a function in the base class that aggregates these members together. The derived class defines some more members and the function aggregates those members to the result of the aggregation of the base. The aggregation function is called in a big loop, hence virtual function are not desired and that creates the problem shown in the main, the same object behaves differently when foo is called (because different function is called on the same object base vs derived version). I've considered some alternatives like using private inheritance which would have been approporiate if the members were not directly accesses in the code. Are there other alternatives to solving this problem, are there other problems with the name hiding other the one described above?

Comment: Please elaborate on "function is called in a big loop, hence virtual function are not desired".

Comment: You may add a "tag" to each object and do appropriate casting with a switch statement inside the loop. But did you actually measure that virtual functions don't perform well enough? I assume that what you mean by "virtual functions are not desired".

Comment: the overhead associated with calling a virtual function due to the indirection plus the extra storage for the vtables and the vptrs, these are just really simple structs as I have mentioned

Comment: @freakish I'm just looking if there are other alternatives...

Comment: Tell me, did you measure that overhead as significant, or are you doing premature optimization based off of superstition?

Comment: you are not really calling the same function when you are using a base class pointer vs a derived class pointer.  You are calling the base class function.

Comment: @ttemple you are correct, updated.

Comment: The alternative to virtual methods is to **manually** does the runtime dispatching according to type. So you have to add a new field to know the runtime type and according to that call the correct method, It seems not more performent than virtual call which is less error prone.

Comment: If you want to get the abstraction power of virtual functions without paying the price, then this ain't gonna work. But it isn't clear whether you really need this power. Why are you using `Base&` at all? Explain your use case in more detail.